# Add a calculated class to an HTML element in angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I render a bunch of user icons on a page. I want to give them a class based on their ID.

**Example user object**

```
{ id: 1234, name: "foo" }
```

**HTML element**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList" class="something-{{ user.id % 10 + 1 }}">
</div>
```

So classes would be like "something-1", "something-2", ... based on the users ID.

The above code doesn't work. No class shows up on the element. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your code is fine, not sure how you test it, but code is okay. For id `1234` it will render `class="something-5"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a try with `ng-init`. In that case your HTML will be

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList" ng-init="myId = (user.id % 10) + 1;" class="something-{{ myId }}">
</div>
```

Comment: Vineet - I am trying to generate classes like "something-1", "something-2", etc. Not conditionally show "something".

Comment: Interesting - but it looks like my original question worked I just had a typo elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class

```
 <div ng-repeat="user in userList" data-ng-class="{class1:user.id===1234}"></div>
```

or you could use a function

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList" class="{{getClassName(user)}}">
</div>
```

the function could be

```
$scope.getClassName = function(user){
    return "class-" + (user.id * 10)+1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build the classes in the controller, so as to keep the view neat, tidy, and clean from JS operations that would be better suited in the controller.

```
users.forEach(function (user) {
  user.klass = 'something-' + (user.id % 10 + 1);
});
```

---

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" class="{{::user.klass}}"> 
<!-- :: added. kill the watchers -->
```